# Big O and sets in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, set, big-o

What are the [Big-O notations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for [Sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) in Javascript? Is it always faster than an array?  Additionally, can you tell me where I should be looking here for sets? (i.e. what category does it fall under... is it hash table?)

Answer (score 0):

`add`, `delete` and `has` is at least O(log n) or even O(1)

`forEach`, `entries`, `values`, `keys` traversal is O(n)

> Is it always faster than an array?

No, traversal is roughly at the same speed.